# How to Add SMS Feature to a Website?On admin Side

Tags: php, joomla, sms

I designed a School Website. In that I want to add `SMS` sending feature(`Bulk and Individual`) on admin side
so that all parents can receive events which are going on school, and also if a student is absent that should be informed to the particular parents phone via `SMS`.

I designed this Feature. But I want to know various Hosting Services all over India, including Pricing.

Here I want to Add Sender Name like LM-xxxx or DA-xxxx etc..
if there is a Yearly or Unlimited Validity plans Let me Know..

Please Suggest me. I have done the project in `PHP(Joomla)`

Comment: quick google search produced this - don't know if it's helpful or not - http://www.thekirankumar.com/blog/2010/08/03/php-script-to-send-free-sms-using-your-160by2-account/

Comment: Thanks A lot @Tim Can You Suggest me Some Sites which can Send Max500-5000 sms Per day they may be Paid or Free.. i Googled But not exact results,,, Please Send them in Answer i will Up vote... Thanks,,,,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For that you have to get GSM device to send SMS through a serial port (usb). You can use a generic GSM module accesible using USB/Serial Cable, or a GSM Phone with a USB/Serial connector supported by your hardware.

[image: SMS gateway device]

1.Open the SMS gateway device and put the SMS card inside.

2.Plug to network in the "power" input, plug the USB cable in the SMS Gateway device and connect the other end to the server using a standard USB port.

3.When you connect the device to the server, wait a few seconds and run `dmesg` command from the command line.You should see something like this [image: screenshot].

This means device has been recognized by the kernel and it's ready to accept commands on a device, like `/dev/ttyACM0`. 
If you're here, the hardware setup is done. If not, please review all steps and be sure that:

- Device is connected and led is blinking in a green color.
- Device is connected to the USB port, both sides of wire, one side to the SMS device, and other side to the server host.
- Device has a SIM card inside, and it's placed properly.

**Configure SMSTools to Use the New Device**

4.Device is managed by a software package called **SMSTools**. You can install `smstools` using the package provided by your Linux Distribution if you use linux.

```
$ sudo apt-get install smstools
```

5.Go to base configuration file,

```
vim /etc/smsd.conf
```

6.Edit this file as

```
devices = GSM1
logfile = /var/log/smsd.log
loglevel = 10

[GSM1]
device = /dev/ttyACM0
incoming = no
pin = 9999
```

Use the PIN assigned to your SIM. Example,for me PIN is "9999".

7.Then, start manually smstools.

```
/usr/bin/smstools start
```

8.Create a file in the server.ex:- `send_sms_test.php` and add this.

```
<?php

$to=$_GET['to'];
$message=$_GET['msg'];

#send sms for multiple users
$to2=array_map('trim',explode(",",$to));

foreach($to2 as $key=>$value){
   $file_name="xxx"; //add a file name u like

   $file = fopen("/var/spool/sms/outgoing/$file_name", "w+");
   fwrite($file,"\n");
   fwrite($file,"To: $to2[$key]");
   fwrite($file,"\n");
   fwrite($file,$message);
   fwrite($file,"\n");
   fwrite($file,"===============");
   fwrite($file,"\n");
   fwrite($file,"HI this is test sms alert");
   if($file==false)
        die("unable to create file");
   fclose($file);

   } // foreach end
?>
```

9.By using API send data through URL.ex;-

```
http://your.host.server.com/send_sms_test.php?to=0123456789,0987654321&msg=tst_for_check_multiple_sms
```

(you can add multiple telephone numbers by comma "," separated)

Or if you want to create this `url` in your script, use `CURL` 
ex:-

```
curl "http://your.host.server.com/send_sms_test.php?to=0123456789,0987654321&msg=tst_for_check_multiple_sms"
```

If you want to check that sms is sent,check on `smsd.log` file,

```
cat /var/log/smsd.log
```

Comment: Thank you @Thusitha Sumanadasa sir,  my i know the Gateway Device Price and sms charge details please send me any url regarding that..

Comment: US $110.77 - 155.08 http://gsmmodemindia.com and http://alibaba.com/product-detail/… sms charges are normal charges and its differ from sim to sim (what you are going to use)

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to purchase a `SMS API` to send sms using your `webapp`.. 
They will provide you a `link` to send sms.. you just need to pass `mobile number and text` to that link and your `sms` will be sent..
for `bulk sms` you can use `any loop like for or while`...

let me know if you want any further guidance..